# Importing AWS downloaded Sentinel-2 data into SNAP software?

Tags: snapping, sentinel-2, amazon-web-services, esa

I have downloaded Sentinel-2 L1C granules from AWS. I saved it as .SAFE format and now have for each tile downloaded as folder structure:

- AUX_DATA
- IMG_DATA
- QI_DATA

i would like to run some algorithms (atmospheric correction, biophysical procesor, etc.) with ESA's SNAP sowftware on these files.

As there is no .xml file downloaded from AWS, how can i import this file-structure into the SNAP software?

So far i can only select each band independently and load in SNAP as one product, but i would like all bands together as one product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sentinel-2 L1C AWS bucket is populated by Sinergise, who also publish a Python library called [sentinelhub-py](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/sentinelhub-py) that allows you to reconstruct the .SAFE format as expected by SNAP including the relevant XML files. The [documentation](http://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aws_cli.html) also explains the differences between the original, compact and reconstructed formats.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I actually downloaded the data with sentinelHub. A parameter to set is "SAFE_FORMAT=True" to get a safe folder structure. Unfortunately no .xml file is being downloaded and so far i haven't found this option in the sentinel-hub documentation.